# Regular expression for name - with (but not starting/ending with) specific special characters

Tags: regex

I need to validate the user input for 'name' field.

Name should satisfy the following requirements.

- Should be only letters (including international characters)
- Should accept - and ' and whitespace (James Horner, James O'Connel, James-reed Horner)
- Should not start or end with the special characters mentioned above.
- Should not be contain two or more special characters mentioned above consecutively
- Length should not be more that 25 (not mandatory)

For that I came up with the following Regular Expression

```
(^([A-Za-z]+([-']?|\s+))+([a-zA-Z])+$){1,25}
```

With the above RE I could validate that string starts with letter, and contains only special characters mentioned above. But could not validate for its length as I used '+'. Also it is not accepting a single letter ( For example : 'a' is also valid name in my case).

How can I validate for all the above mentioned cases?

Comment: Have a look at `lookahead`: http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

An acceptable solution would be:

```
^(?!.*?([' -])\1)\b([a-z '-]{1,25})\b$
```

with the modifier `i` for ignoring upper/lowercase characters. A regex101 demo can be [seen here](https://regex101.com/r/yF7kR6/2).

Comment: A little optimization`^(?!.*?([' -]).*\1)\b([[:alpha:] '-]{1,25})\b$`

Comment: @Costas Wouldn't your expression fail for `my-name with-something`?

Comment: @Costas From what the OP states, they can appear more than once, but not continuously. So: `a-b-s` is correct, whereas `a--b` is not. Which is why I didn't use `([' -]).*\1` in pattern.